# AngularJS update ng-click scope from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-ng-click

I'm creating an ng-repeat and using an ng-model changing the amount of elements that are visible, this works fine. Also I'm creating a pagination using ng-click and ng-class, and here's where I'm having the problem.

I'm defining some variables in a controller's scope, such as amount-limit, total-pages, current-page like this:

```
// definitions
$scope.clients;
$scope.clientsAmount;

// amount of visible clients
$scope.limitArray = [8,12,16];
$scope.clientsLimit = 8;

// function to get the amount of pages
function getPages(els, limit) {
    // get the total pages considrering the amount of elements
    $scope.totalPages = Math.ceil(els/limit);
    $log.log( 'get - total => ', $scope.totalPages );
}
```

Then I have some functions to go to the next/previous page. At page load those work fine, but when I change clientsLimit amount, even though the controller's scope value is updated (using $watch I call the getPages function again using the new value of clientsLimit) but when I click in the buttons with the ng-click directive the values for pages are not changed. The param is to check if this is the last/first or next/previous buttons.

```
// NEXT BUTTON
    $scope.nextBtn = function(param){
        $log.log( 'value => ',  value );
        // check if this is not the last page and the param is true
        // go to the next page
        if( $scope.currentPage !== $scope.totalPages && param ) {

            $scope.currentPage++;

        } else if (!param) {

            $scope.currentPage = $scope.totalPages;

        }// conditional end

    };// next button end

// PREVIOUS BUTTON
    $scope.prevBtn = function(param){

        // check if this is not the first page and the param is true
        // go to the preivious page
        if( $scope.currentPage !== 1 && param ) {

            $scope.currentPage--;

        } else if ( !param ) {

            $scope.currentPage = 1;

        }// conditional end

    };// previous button end
```

This is the HTML

```
<li ng-class="firstPageCheck()">
  <a href aria-label="First" ng-click="prevBtn(false)">
    <span aria-hidden="true">First</span>
  </a>
</li>

<li ng-class="firstPageCheck()">
  <a href aria-label="Previous" ng-click="prevBtn(true)">
    <span aria-hidden="true">Previous</span>
  </a>
</li>

<li ng-class="lastPageCheck()">
  <a href aria-label="Next" ng-click="nextBtn(true, value=totalPages)">
    <span aria-hidden="true">Next</span>
  </a>
</li>
<li ng-class="lastPageCheck()">
  <a href aria-label="Last" ng-click="nextBtn(false, value=totalPages)">
    <span aria-hidden="true">Last</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

As I said the ng-class and ng-click are not reflecting the changes in the controller's scope.

Here's a plunkr with the files and the JSON data:

http://plnkr.co/edit/eVSW449vJ5cv6WWvyJhc?p=info

=======================================

**EDIT**

Hi. Basically this is the "*I'm an idiot edit*" :P. Turns out that I was adding more than one instance of the controller, therefore the select ng-model was updating just that controller instance, while the others (yes... at some point I included up to 3 :S) kept the value setted on run time.

Here's an updated Plunker link with just one controller instance and everything working ok with the pagination:
http://plnkr.co/edit/eVSW449vJ5cv6WWvyJhc

Answer (score 0):

I looked at you code and I didn't find import angular-ui, because you using pagination. Check out: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ 
and simple example:

```
 'http://plnkr.co/edit/xxjIBw71hDp9AHSrEhfp?p=preview
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel!!, I'll give that a try. Never really thought about going that route, since creating a custom filter and adding some functions using built-in directives didn't seem too hard,  I never considered using other directives, since eventually I'll turn the pagination into a custom directive.